# Flask Form Submit does nothing

Tags: python, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

Clicking on the submit button literally does nothing. Submitting a blank form will trigger the validation for the required fields, but filling out the form as required results in the form not submitting/submit button doing nothing. The template has the CSRF_Token, Submit Button is in the form tag, and the form tag has an action attribute pointing in the right direction. Chrome doesn't bark any errors so I'm stuck on how to proceed.

views.py

```
@blueprint.route("register/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """Renders register page."""
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not form.validate_on_submit():
            return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                                   form=form, form_success=False, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])
        company, err = get_company(form.organization.data)
        if err:
            company, err = create_company(form.organization.data)
            if err:
                return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                                       form=form, form_success=False, message=err, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])
        customer, err = get_or_create_customer(
            form.first_name.data + " " + form.last_name.data, form.email.data,
            company_id, form.position.data, phone_number
        )
        if err:
            return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                                   form=form, form_success=False, message=err, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])
        if err:
            return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                                   form=form, form_success=False, message=err, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])
        else:
            return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                                   form=form, form_success=True, message=success_msg, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])
    return render_template('main/register.html', page_title="Service Registration",
                           form=form, media_types=current_app.config["ACCEPTED_"
                                                          "MEDIA_TYPE"])


@blueprint.route("register/", methods=['POST'])
def upload_register():
    """Handles file upload POSTs."""
    first_name = request.form.get("first_name")
    last_name = request.form.get("last_name")
    name = request.form.get("first_name") + " " + request.form.get("last_name")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    filename = request.form.get("filename")
    file_type = request.form.get("file_type")

    if filename == '':
        response = make_response("No selected file")
        return response, 400
    if check_file_type(file_type):
        filename = clean_filename(filename)
        filename = secure_filename(filename)
        filename = unique_filename(filename)
        response = generate_presigned_post(filename, file_type)
        # CREATE DB REFERENCE
        url = "http://nevcodocs.s3.amazonaws.com/Uploads/{}".format(filename)
        instance = CustomerFileUpload.query.filter_by(url=url).first()
        if not instance:
            instance = CustomerFileUpload(url=url, email=email, name=name)
            db.session.add(instance)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            instance.update(created_at=datetime.utcnow())
        return response, 200
    else:
        response = make_response("Invalid file type")
        return response, 500
```

javascript/jquery

```
// Enables/disables form submission and colors button accordingly
        var enableSubmit = function(enabled) {
            if (enabled) {
                $('#submit_ticket').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#submit_ticket').removeAttr('style');
            } else {
                $('#submit_ticket').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#submit_ticket').attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(244, 121, 32, 0.5) !important; border-color: rgba(244, 121, 32, 0.25) !important;');
            }
        };

$('#ticket-form').submit(function(event) {
            enableSubmit(false);
            showSpinner(true);
            var validated = true;

            var didSelectFile = true;
            didSelectFile = validateField('#upload') && validated;

            validated = didSelectFile && validated;

            if (didSelectFile && !validateContentType()) {
                $('invalid-upload-alert').show();
                validated = false;
            } else {
                $('#invalid-upload-alert').hide();
            }
            if (validated) {
                $('#filename').val($('#upload').val());
                $('#file_type').val($('#upload').prop('files')[0].type);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/register/',
                    data: $('#ticket-form').serialize()
                }).done(function(data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    for (var key in data.data.fields) {
                        formData.append(key, data.data.fields[key]);
                    }
                    formData.append('file', $('#upload').prop('files')[0]);
                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.onload = function() {
                        showSpinner(false);
                        $('#ticket-form-failed').removeClass("support-form-show");
                        $('#ticket-form-failed').addClass("support-form-hide");
                        $('#ticket-form').removeClass("support-form-show");
                        $('#ticket-form').addClass("support-form-hide");
                        $('#ticket-form-success').removeClass("support-form-hide");
                        $('#ticket-form-success').addClass("support-form-show");
                    };
                    req.onerror = function() {
                        showSpinner(false);
                        $('#ticket-form-failed').removeClass("support-form-hide");
                        $('#ticket-form-failed').addClass("support-form-show");
                    };
                    req.open('POST', data.url);
                    req.send(formData);
                }).fail(function(err) {
                    showSpinner(false);
                    $('#ticket-form-failed').removeClass("support-form-hide");
                    $('#ticket-form-failed').addClass("support-form-show");
                });
            } else {
                showSpinner(false);
                enableSubmit(true);
            }
            {% endif %}
            if (!validated) {
                event.preventDefault();
                showSpinner(false);
                enableSubmit(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This looks SO complex. Looks to me you are missing a preventDefault. `$('#ticket-form').on("submit",function(event) { event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Also, why is there an `{% endif %}` near the end of the function?

Comment: I'm using jinja hence the {% endif %}. I tried adding the preventDefault, but the submit button still doesn't do anything. I've also redacted the code so it might be confusing.

Comment: Please post the rendered form in pure HTML (view-source) and the script as it looks in the page

Comment: Problem with that is the source code is extremely long.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written looks really complicated, why not try something easy like-

```
@app.route("/connect",methods=['GET','POST'])
def connect():
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('connect.html')
    if request.method=="POST":
        return render_template('Thankyou.html',name=request.form['name])
```

in you **views.py** and in your **connect.html** form just write-

```
<form name="connect" method="post" action="{{ url_for('connect') }}">
        <input class="t1" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email ID">
        <input class="t2" type="text"  id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <button class="btn btn-primary but" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

the final page, **Thankyou.html** can look like this-

```
<p>Thanks for contacting me, {{ name }} </p>
```

Comment: Well, I'm using this form to get the data the user inputs into the multitude of fields I have, and create a ticket with said info for a customer service software (FreshDesk) so it's more complicated than this.

Comment: So you basically need to get all the data in those fields to your server and process them and then display a ticket based on the processed data?